# defining a function which calls another function for a variety of strings python

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.3

I have a code which finds anagrams of a string in a dictionary file. I want to create a function which tests a variety of strings called test_find_anagrams(). It should test at least 6 different strings.

This is the code i have which tests a single string in a file.

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    str1 = sorted(str1)
    str2 = sorted(str2)
    return str1 == str2

def get_dictionary_word_list():
    with open('dictionarys.txt') as f:
        return f.read().split()

def find_anagrams(str):
    return [word for word in get_dictionary_word_list() if anagram(word,str)]
```

So far i have this code to test different strings, It works on the first string in the list but doesnt return anything for any string after. What else do i need to put in the code for it to work?

```
def test_find_anagrams():
    stringlist = [('aces'), ('sidebar'), ('adverb'), ('fuels'), ('hardset'), ('praised')]
    for str1 in stringlist:
        return [word for word in get_dictionary_word_list() if anagram(word,str1)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only "works on the first string in the list" because you return from inside the loop.  Keep track of your result outside of the loop.

```
def test_find_anagrams():
    stringlist = [('aces'), ('sidebar'), ('adverb'), ('fuels'), ('hardset'), ('praised')]
    result = []
    for str1 in stringlist:
        result.extend(word for word in get_dictionary_word_list() if anagram(word,str1))
    return result
```

Comment: Oh yes thank you. How would i get the result for each str1 so that it is printed/ returned separately and not as one long list.
eg 
('anagram1','anagram2')
('anagram3', 'anagram4')

Comment: You could make result a dictionary.  Then instead of `result.extend` do `result[str1] = [...]`.  Then you would be able to index result lists by string.

Comment: That brings the error TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Change `result = []` to `result = {}` (make it a dictionary).

Comment: Ah that works for the first bit but now instead of returning the anagrams it returns {'praised': <generator object <genexpr> at 0x05E14B48>?

Comment: Brackets, not parenthesis: `result[str1] = [word for word in get_dictionary_word_list() if anagram(word,str1)]`.  Brackets are for list comprehensions and parenthesis are for generator expressions.